# C# Security RegistryPermissions demand popup

Tags: c#, security, permissions, registry

I have this code but I don't seem to understand exactly the purpose of the permission Demand method

```
 RegistryPermission registryPermission = new RegistryPermission(RegistryPermissionAccess.AllAccess, @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run");
registryPermission.Demand();

RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
if (checkBoxLoadStartup.Checked)
{
     //make an entry in the registry to make this program run at start up
     regKey.SetValue(Application.ExecutablePath.ToString(), Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
}
else
{
    //delete the entry
    regKey.DeleteValue(Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
}
```

I expected to see a window popping up and asking me to allow the permissions to write the registry. Instead I got an exception. To make it work I added:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

in app.manifest and now I don't see any popups but I'm allowed to change the values.

Is it possible to show a popup asking a question to give permissions to change the registry and based on the given permissions to modify or not the registry key?